# How to prevent Rails 6 from blocking my AWS EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks, ruby-on-rails-6

I have some Rails 6 applications, deployed at AWS, via Opsworks.

After upgrading to Rails 6 the app blocks the health check of its own instance and it causes the load balancer to take the instance down.

I would like to know how to whitelist all my EC2 instances automatically with dynamic IP addresses? Instead of adding one by one to config/application.rb?

Thanks

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Whitelist one hostname
  config.hosts << "hostname"
  # Whitelist a test domain
  config.hosts << /application\.local\Z/
  # config.hosts.clear 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The work-around that worked for me was

```
config.hosts.clear
```

Comment: Thank you, It looks like this is the current workaround for mee too, but it is not ideal since it disables the feature. Best

Comment: I do not think this is really safe as in this way, you will allow all hosts access to your application. You should rather whitelist the hosts you want.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question a while back. A safer solution would be reading the IP addresses from environmental variables that can be set from the AWS console.

```
config.hosts << ENV["INSTANCE_IP"]
config.hosts << ENV["INSTANCE_IP2"]
...
config.hosts << ENV["INSTANCE_IPn"]
```

At least in this way it does not require a new git commit every time the IP address changes when the instance has a dynamic IP.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to allow the Health Checker user agent, add this to your `production.log`

```
  config.host_authorization = {
    exclude: ->(request) { request.user_agent =~ /ELB-HealthChecker/ }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove any `config.hosts << "hostname"` from `application.rb` config - then rails won't block hosts

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it has been resolved in the latest versions atleast works on 6.1 and above

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#actiondispatch-hostauthorization

You can exclude certain requests from Host Authorization checks by setting config.host_configuration.exclude:

```
# Exclude requests for the /healthcheck/ path from host checking
Rails.application.config.host_configuration = {
  exclude: ->(request) { request.path =~ /healthcheck/ }
}
```

Comment: Note this is incorrect. `Rails.application.config.host_configuration` does not exist. it should be `Rails.application.config.host_authorization`